# How to add default value for multiple columns in a table of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to add a default value for multiple columns in a SQL Server table. Is this query of mine valid? Do we have any better way to write this query?

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD DEFAULT 'Chicago' FOR Location
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD DEFAULT '60601' FOR Zip
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD DEFAULT 'A' FOR Emp_Status
```

I may need to set up the default value for 10 columns like this. I am wondering if my query can be written in an optimized way?

Comment: *"Does my below query is valid?"* Have you run it and found out? *"I may need to set up the default value for 10 columns like this. I am wondering my query can be written in an optimized way?"* What optimisations are you looking for here? You can't really "speed up" a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT`, but then they are very fast to do as they don't perform any DML operations. Also, why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server? 2 of them are also **completely** unsupported, and the other doesn't have much extended support left either.

Comment: You can add all the constraints in one statement, though per @Larnu this won't do much of anything in terms of performance: `ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Employee_Location DEFAULT 'Chicago' FOR Location, CONSTRAINT DF_Employee_Zip DEFAULT '60601' FOR Zip, ...` I do recommend always naming your constraints explicitly as long as you're scripting them anyway, since this will allow you to drop/disable/change them later if need be (which is far more of a headache with system-generated names).

Comment: If you also created the prior CREATE TABLE statement, you could include those default constraints in the CREATE TABLE statement as well. Also, I would suggest that you give those default constraints an explicit name (`ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Employee_Location DEFAULT 'Chicago' FOR Location` for example). That will be handy if you ever need to drop those constraints easily.

Comment: This is honestly a bizarre question - this is DDL that you only run as a one-off - are you repeatedly needing to change the default values?